# Decode a Swift type that is a wrapped Codable type with an extra Codable property

Tags: swift, codable

I've got a Codable type, let's say `Car`, that is defined as:

```
struct Car: Codable {
    let age: Int
    let color: String
}
```

I can encode/decode this just fine.

With my persistence system, when an object is stored it gets assigned an `_id` property, which is a `String`, e.g. `5cae04b533376609456d40ed`.

As such, when I read the `Data` from the persistent store and then try to decode it there are extra bytes in there that represent the `_id` property and its associated `String` value.

I'm not in control of the various types that can be encoded and stored in the store. The only restriction on them is that they are `Codable`.

What I want to be able to do is decode the `Data` that I get when reading from the store (with the `_id` stuff included) into a type that is something like `Wrapped<T: Codable>`, which would be defined as something like (in the simplest form):

```
struct Wrapped<T: Codable> {
    let _id: String
    let value: T
}
```

However, I'm not sure to go about this.

One attempt I made was to to define a custom `decode` function but that didn't get very far as I can't seem to access the `T` type's `CodingKeys`, which makes things, as far as I can tell, impossible with that approach.

Maybe there's another approach that would make things work as I'd like?

Comment: So should `_id` be part of the encoded value?

Comment: Nope, it should only be available once some decoding has happened, as part of some other type (at least that's what I'm assuming will be a requirement)

Comment: You shouldn't need to access `T`'s coding keys, just do `value = T(from: decoder)` in your custom `decode` function.

Comment: That fails though because there are extra bytes taken up by the `_id` key-value pair. Unless I've misunderstood what you're suggesting?

Comment: I wrote an answer showing what I meant

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom decode function for your `Wrapped` type that parses out the `_id` and then passes the decoder along to the wrapped type so it can decode it's own properties:

```
struct Wrapped<T: Codable>: Decodable {
    let _id: String
    let value: T

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case _id
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        _id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: ._id)
        value = try T(from: decoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, after some tweaking with my custom `Decoder`: https://github.com/myfreeweb/SwiftCBOR/pull/39

I needed to remove the `precondition` check in the `Decoder` that there hadn't already been a container created.

Worth noting that it does need to decode the whole thing twice, but that's not really an issue for me, at least not right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare that the `_id` property shouldn't decoded by defining your custom `CodingKeys` and omitting `_id` from there. You also need to assign a default value to the non-decoded properties (`_id` in your case) if you want to use the automatically synthetised initializer.

For a concrete type:

```
struct Car: Codable {
    let age: Int
    let color: String
    let _id:Int = 0

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case age, color
    }
}
```

You can achieve this for all your persisted types.

If you don't want to create the `CodingKeys` enum for all persisted types, you could follow the generic wrapper type approach you started, but you'll need to create custom `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)` methods.

```
struct Persisted<T: Codable>: Codable {
    let _id:Int = 0
    let value:T

    init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {
        value = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(T.self)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(value)
    }
}
```